# pkgsearch: Error in as.POSIXct.default(date): do not know how to convert 'date' to class "POSIXct"

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse

The R package `pkgsearch` throws the following error when using `select` command from `dplyr`:

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(date): do not know how to convert 'date'
>   to class "POSIXct"

Any help, please.

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
library(pkgsearch)

PkgMYaseen208 <-
    pkg_search(
          query  = "Yaseen"
        , format = c("short", "long")[1]
        , from   = 1
        , size   = 25
        ) %>% 
        arrange(package) 

PkgMYaseen208
#> - "Yaseen" -------------------------------- 20 packages in 0.009 seconds - 
#>   #     package          version by                 @ title               
#>   1  65 agriTutorial     0.1.4   Rodney Edmondson  9M Tutorial Analysis...
#>   2  88 bayesammi        0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Bayesian Estimati...
#>   3 100 baystability     0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Bayesian Stabilit...
#>   4  91 DiallelAnalysisR 0.1.1   Muhammad Yaseen   3y Diallel Analysis ...
#>   5  88 dmai             0.4.0   Muhammad Yaseen   6d Divisia Monetary ...
#>   6  91 eda4treeR        0.2.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Experimental Desi...
#>   7  97 gvcR             0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Genotypic Varianc...
#>   8  91 PakPC2017        1.0.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Pakistan Populati...
#>   9  91 PakPMICS2014Ch   0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   2y Multiple Indicato...
#>  10  94 PakPMICS2014HH   0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   2y Multiple Indicato...
#>  11  98 PakPMICS2014HL   0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   2y Multiple Indicato...
#>  12  94 PakPMICS2014Wm   0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   2y Multiple Indicato...
#>  13  91 ppcSpatial       0.2.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Spatial Analysis ...
#>  14  94 PSLM2015         0.2.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Pakistan Social a...
#>  15  86 qccrs            0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   6M Quality Control C...
#>  16  87 rgsp             0.2.0   Muhammad Yaseen   7M Repetitive Group ...
#>  17  98 stability        0.5.0   Muhammad Yaseen   8M Stability Analysi...
#>  18  96 StroupGLMM       0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen   3y R Codes and Datas...
#>  19  88 SupMZ            0.1.0   Muhammad Yaseen  13h Detecting Structu...
#>  20  87 VetResearchLMM   1.0.0   Muhammad Yaseen   1y Linear Mixed Mode...

PkgMYaseen208 %>%
        dplyr::select(package)
#> - "Yaseen" -------------------------------- 20 packages in 0.009 seconds -
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'score'.
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'version'.
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'maintainer_name'.
#> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'date'.
#> Error in as.POSIXct.default(date): do not know how to convert 'date' to class "POSIXct"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be an issue with the attributes of the dataset (`str(PkgMYaseen208)`).  One option is to convert to `data.frame` and then `select`

```
library(dplyr)
PkgMYaseen208 %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  dplyr::select(package)
#          package
#1      agriTutorial
#2         bayesammi
#3      baystability
#4  DiallelAnalysisR
#5              dmai
#6         eda4treeR
#7              gvcR
#8         PakPC2017
#9    PakPMICS2014Ch
#10   PakPMICS2014HH
#1   PakPMICS2014HL
#2   PakPMICS2014Wm
#3       ppcSpatial
#4         PSLM2015
#15            qccrs
#16             rgsp
#17        stability
#18       StroupGLMM
#19            SupMZ
#20   VetResearchLMM
```