# Getting output having quotes and no quotes

Tags: r, paste, quotes, factors

**Required Output**

```
c('A'=5,'B'=5,'C'=5)
```

**What Got**

```
df1 <- factor(LETTERS[1:3])
paste(levels(df1), 5, sep = "=")
#> [1] "A=5" "B=5" "C=5"

noquote(capture.output(cat(paste(shQuote(levels(df1)), 5, sep = "="), sep = ",")))
#> [1] 'A'=5,'B'=5,'C'=5
```

Any help to get the required output, please.

Comment: @RonakShah: No it is not giving the required output.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for your useful comment. Please change your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `setNames` to name the vector and `rep` to create a numeric vector.

```
setNames(rep(5, length(df1)), df1)

#A B C 
#5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for your help. I do another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56301399/707145).

Answer (score 1):

```
ltrs <- LETTERS[1:3]
nbrs <- c(5,5,5)
names(nbrs) = ltrs
nbrs %>% dput
```

Comment: Thanks @Andreé for your answer. Your given code gives the output `c(A = 5, B = 5, C = 5)`. However, the required output is `c('A'=5,'B'=5,'C'=5)`. Any thoughts, please.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replicate`

```
setNames(replicate(length(df1), 5), df1)
# A B C      
# 5 5 5
```

---

Or more compactly

```
library(tibble)
deframe(tibble(df1, 5))
#   A B C 
#  5 5 5
```